# How do i round integers to the highest multiple of 10, not rounding down just round up, in python

Tags: python, math, rounding

I have been stuck on this for a while, I have come across many different round functions but they round floats or round up and down, I am looking for a way just to round up even if the number is 61 then it rounds up to 70, is there a way I can do this in python

Comment: From 61 to 70 you should code it by yourself

Comment: Integer division by 10 followed by multiplication by 10 and additional addition of 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should work fine

```
ceil(61 / 10) * 10
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only works in Python 3, since `/` will do an integer division in Python 2 by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulus operator, which divides the given numbers and produces the remainder:

```
def rounder(num, d):
    return num - num % -d
```

Result:

```
>>> print(*('{}: {}'.format(n, rounder(n, 10)) for n in range(15)), sep='\n')
0: 0
1: 10
2: 10
3: 10
4: 10
5: 10
6: 10
7: 10
8: 10
9: 10
10: 10
11: 20
12: 20
13: 20
14: 20
```

Comment: No need for the subtraction or the extra `%d` operation: just do `return num + (-num) % d`. (Or even `return num - num % -d`.)

Comment: Much tidier. Thanks, @MarkDickinson.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ceiling function, which always rounds up

```
import math

def roundupby(n, by):
    return math.ceil(n / by) * by

print (roundupby(61, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use modulo operator.

```
number += (number%10) and (10 - number%10)
```